# How to get encrypted resouce bundle?

Tags: java, encryption, resources, bundle, message

Presupposition：
we had encrypt international message resources into a jar file.
We use ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME) to get message resource before encryption.

Problem:
How can I read the message resources after jared all resouces to a file?

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities:

1. **Load it yourself**:
   When the complete resource file is encrypted you need to handle the loading of it yourself.
   Since Jar files are just zip packages, you can extract any content. So you can read and decrypt the correct properties file and then load it as ResourceBundle.
   See the following lib to access jar resources:
   https://github.com/IsNull/archimedesJ/blob/master/src/archimedesJ/util/PackageUtil.java
   And the following strategy to load the correct file:
   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle(java.lang.String%2C%20java.util.Locale%2C%20java.lang.ClassLoader)
2. **Inject a ResourceBundle [Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern)**:
   If you only encrypt the values of the properties file, you can stick to the ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME). Now, it will return rubbish as the strings are encrypted. So you just wrap the ResourceBundle in a custom proxy to decrypt the values:

Usage example:

```
ResourceBundle mybundle = new EncryptedResourceBundle(ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME), "mypassword");
```

You define EncryptedResourceBundle as a subclass of ResourceBundle and proxy all the public methods and redirect them to the underlying original. Overwrite the "getString" method as well, but now you can transparently decrypt the returned value on the fly:

```
public class EncryptedResourceBundle extends ResourceBundle
    private final ResourceBundle original;
    private final String password;

    public EncryptedResourceBundle(ResourceBundle original, String password){
        this.original = original;
        this.password = password;
    }

    ... // proxy all public methods here

    @Overwrite
    public String getString(String key){

        String encrypted = original.getString(key);

        return decrypt(encrypted, password);
    }

    private String decrypt(String data, String password){
        ...
    }

}
```

If security is important, you probably do not want to store the real password but using tokens derived from your original password.